# How to do twos compliment with larger decimal values?

Tags: twos-complement

I am trying to do twos compliment of the following: 34-11.

After trying to solve the problem myself and then getting the answer from a calculator I am doing it completely wrong after following many tutorials.

I converted 34 and 11 to binary first getting 100010 and 1011 respectively. I then got 0101 by 1s notation and adding 1 after.

Finally, 100010 + 0101 = 100111.

From what I can find this is not the correct answer. I would appreciate if someone could walk me through it, thanks.

Comment: Try padding the original binary values out to at least 7 bits: `0100010` and `0001011`. Then do the math again and see what you get.

Comment: @beaker what do you mean by padding?

Comment: Exactly what I showed in my example. `0100010` is exactly the same number as `100010`, right? Make both of the numbers 7 bits by adding 0's the front, then do your 2's complement and add.

Comment: @beaker  Oh now I understand you. I did that and got 0100010 + 1110100 which gave the answer 0010110. There was a remainder of 1 but from what I understand this is discarded, is that correct?

Also, why would I make the numbers 7 bits and do I do this everytime? Thanks.

Comment: That should be `1110101` for `-11`, right?

Comment: 1) The sign bit should always be present (positive or negative) and 2) the length of the binary values should be the same, with the sign bit extended as you did in this case.